# Assign an array from method

Tags: java, arrays, methods, assign

I am trying to sort an array but I got problem when I'm trying to assign the value of it, how can I fix it ?

this is the method to assign the value of array

```
public void Sort1() {
    for (int i = 0; i < numStudent; i++) {
        x[i] = student[i].getScore(0);
    }
    int tampung;
    for (int i = 0; i < numStudent; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < numStudent - (i + 1); j++) {
            if (x[j] > x[j + 1]) {
                tampung = x[j];
                x[j] = x[j + 1];
                x[j + 1] = tampung;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and i want to get the array from here

```
public int getScore(int i){
    return test[i-1];
}
```

Comment: This will throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, because of calling `getScore()` with a `0` argument.

Comment: where are you initializing the array? and where are you defining test[]?

Comment: what 'problem' are you having? add some detail...

Comment: the problem is when i'm trying to initializing the array. it doesn't work, i think the problem on when i'm trying to intialize the value of x[]

Comment: thank you for your response guys, now I can fix it, i don't need to assign the value of test[] to x but i just only need to call it then sort it. ty

Answer (score 1):

Just use Java sort method, with Comparator. ( Assuming you want sort students based on their score)

```
    Arrays.sort(students, new Comparator<Student>(){
         public int compare(Student sd1, Student sd2) {
        return sd1.getScore(0).compareTo(sd2.getScore(0));
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x[i] = student[i].getScore(0);
```

Shouldn't this be called as

```
 x[i] = student[i].getScore(i);
```

complete code should be like this.

```
public void Sort1() {
for (int i = 1; i <= numStudent; i++) {
    x[i] = student[i].getScore(i);
}
int tampung;
for (int i = 0; i < numStudent; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < numStudent - (i + 1); j++) {
        if (x[j] > x[j + 1]) {
            tampung = x[j];
            x[j] = x[j + 1];
            x[j + 1] = tampung;
        }
    }
}
}

public int getScore(int i){
    return test[i-1];
}
```

Comment: How does this answers the question?

Comment: I have edited the answer, Isn't this answer the question now?

Comment: I don't know, actually. The question is non very clear.

Comment: yeah ................

Answer (score 0):

Simple [bubble sorting](http://mathbits.com/MathBits/Java/arrays/Bubble.htm) check the link, you don't need to nest `for-loop` but continue until no swaps have occurred, meaning that the array is in the proper sorted order.

```
while ( flag )
{
    flag = false;
    for( j=0;  j < numStudent -1;  j++ )
    {
        if ( x[ j ] > x[j+1] )   // change to < for descending sort
        {
            tampung = x[ j ];                //swap elements
            x[ j ] = x[ j+1 ];
            x[ j+1 ] = tampung;
            flag = true;
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Since when does a simple loop work in bubble sort?

Comment: Are you trying to suggest that bubble sort doesn't require nested loop? That would mean its complexity is `O(n)` which would mean it would be best sorting algorithm which exists (which is kind of not true since this algorithm is one of slowest).

Comment: nope, i said you don't need to nest 2 for-loops

Comment: Now it looks better.

Comment: i was editing to fit OP needs and not simply copy paste... sorry for the delay.... btw, would be great a sorting algorithm with `O(n)` complexity... xD